# Merging to HDR in Camera Raw 9.6.*

Tags: photoshop, hdr, adobe-camera-raw

Itried shoting high dynamic range images yeterday, set up my Nikon D7000 Bracketing and went to some beautiful places.. so I shot few captures and now I have problem with merging. I watched tutorials on youtube, everything is clear but they are using old Camera Raw plugin, I have the latest version Camera Raw 9.6.1 and software interface is not the same, I can not find where is the "merge to hdr" hidden..

any suggestions?

here is my screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the relevant images and right click on one of them in order to show a context menu.

[image: Merge To HDR menu]

Comment: There is not any context menu on images